# Accessing template friend function of class in main.

Tags: c++, templates, function, friend

I am having a hard time finding a simple solution to this. I am implementing an expression tree using the following classes, I declare a friend function of class Tree. My problem comes when I try to get it started in main.

```
template<class object> class Tree;
template<class object> Tree<object>::expTree(Tree<object> *&T);  // ERROR

template<class object>
struct Node
{
  object info;
  Node *next;
  Node<object>():info(0), next(NULL) {}
  Node<object>(const object &element, Node *n = NULL):
    info(element), next(n){}
};
template<class object>
class Stack
{
public:
  Stack();
  ~Stack();
  void makestackempty();
  bool stackEmpty() const;
  void push(object &item);
  void pop (object &item);
  void printStack() const;
private:
  Node<object> *top;
};
template<class object>
struct TreeNode
{
  object info;
  TreeNode *right;
  TreeNode *left;
  TreeNode()
  {}
};

template<class object>
class Tree
{
private:
  TreeNode<object> *root;
public:
  Tree();
  ~Tree();
  Tree(const Tree<object> &rhs);  // copy
  void operator=(const Tree<object> &rhs);
  void copyconst(TreeNode<object> *orig, TreeNode<object> *&rhs);
  void makeEmpty(TreeNode<object> *&tree);
  bool isEmpty()const;
  friend Tree<object> expTree(Tree<object> *&T){
    buildTree(T.root);
  };
  void buildTree(TreeNode<object> *&tree);
  void printTree(TreeNode<object> *&tree)const;
};
```

In main, I get "error: expTree was not declared in this scope."
I also get, " error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before â;â token"
on the second line of this code.. 
Anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
template<class object> Tree<object>::expTree(Tree<object> *&T);  // ERROR
                     //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cause of the error
```

This function template is actually a free function, and will be a friend of the class `Tree`. So it should be written as:

```
template<class object> expTree(Tree<object> *&T);
```

That is, remove `Tree<object>::` from the declaration. I just realized that it is missing the return type, and I suppose you mean `Tree<object>` to be the return type (and `Tree<object>::` is a typo in your code). If so, then write this:

```
template<class object> Tree<object> expTree(Tree<object> *&T);
```

<sub>I would like to comment on your style of naming the template parameters and arguments. It is customary to use `T`, `U`, `V` etc for template parameters, not for function argument. So it feels good when you write the declaration as:</sub>

```
 template<class T> Tree<T> expTree(Tree<T> *&object);
```

<sub>Well I just swapped the names.</sub>

Comment: Yes, I understand the naming. I have a weird professor though. Haha. This function is actually void returning. so I have updated that line to :
    template<class object> void expTree(Tree<object> *&T);

and have changed the other declarations accordingly. I am now getting an error message that I dont know what it means. :(

_ In function `main':
: undefined reference to `void expTree<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >(Tree<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >*&)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
_

Comment: Also note that inline friend functions are only accessible by means of ADL. I don't know how that goes if there is a previous definition though.

Comment: About your undefined reference error - you havent defined expTree function anywhere that compiler/linker can find it.

Comment: @K-ballo I've tried several ways of declaring this friend function with no success. Maybe it's a bug. Any alternative ways of initializing this? I need to initialize building a tree. My main currently consists of: 
    Tree<string> *T;
    cout << "Enter postfix expression to convert:" << endl;
    expTree(*&T);

Comment: @j_kubik  I've tried declaring outside of the class with no success. Where would you suggest I define the function? Or any alternatives? How could I initialize a normal member function of class Tree in main?

Comment: @stef0526: You should not write `expTree(*&T);`. Instead, you should write `expTree(T);`, as you already have define `T` as `Tree<string> *T;`

Comment: You should do it in header - you should do it as soon as everything neede for execution of this function is already declared - i guess just after Tree class declaration is good enough (if you don't use stuff defined later on in function's body of course). If you are still having problems post more code.